# Split Screen with Vim + GitBash in Cmder

Tags: conemu, cmder

Using Cmder 1.3.2 on Win7.

I'm trying to set up a task (or even better, a startup config) that gives me Vim on one side and a GitBash shell on the other.

GitBash is already specified as my named startup task.

When I use this as a task to start Vim with a split screen, I get the Windows console rather than GitBash on the other side:

"C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\vim.exe"

-new_console:s50H

I must be looking right over this, but is there a way to specify GitBash for that new console?

Comment: Screenshots. Your question is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

```
-cur_console:d:C:\YourDirectoryHere"C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\vim.exe"

-cur_console:as50H  -cur_console:d:C:\YourDirectoryHere C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe --login -i
```

This gets you Vim in a 50% pane on the left, and GitBash in a 50% pane on the right.